# New User with Federated Login Not being Recognized

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid, federated-identity

I am using the Google App Engine Python Federated Login which uses OpenID to let users log in with existing accounts.  I want the user to be directed to a page where they fill out some extra information about them such as a username and short bio.  Right now after logging in users are being directed to this handler and then if they have a username I want them to stay on this page otherwise I want them redirected to /profile

```
class Tester(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        global visits
        logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) 

        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            currentregistereduser = None
            try:
                user_db_qry = User.query(User.theid == user.federated_identity())
                user_db_list = user_db_qry.fetch(1)
                #this is the line that is causing the error
                currentregistereduser = user_db_list[0]
            except IndexError:
                #I could do something here to fix it but I am not sure what
            if currentregistereduser:
                if not currentregistereduser.username:
                    self.redirect("/profile")
                else:
                    self.render("tester.html", user=user, logout=logout)
```

The problem is that I am getting an IndexError when I try to do currentregistereduser = user_db_list[0] on a new user but it works fine on an existing user.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?  I have to do the same thing on my /profile page to identify the user so I doesn't help much to just redirect them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that is happening is because your query to the datastore is coming back empty (which is expected in the case of a new user in your situation). One way to get around that would be to check if the lists exists, and if so, process:

```
class Tester(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        global visits
        logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            currentregistereduser = None
            user_db_qry = User.query(User.theid == user.federated_identity())
            user_db_list = user_db_qry.fetch(1)
            # Check to see if the query returned anything at all - if so, assign
            # the value to currentregistereduser; it not, it will remain None
            if user_db_list:
              currentregistereduser = user_db_list[0]

            if currentregistereduser:
                if not currentregistereduser.username:
                    self.redirect("/profile")
                else:
                    self.render("tester.html", user=user, logout=logout)

        # Assuming the code continues here...
```

Comment: but the user should exist shouldn't it?  this all is happening right after they log in for the first time with their OpenID.  what can I do with them if they don't exist for a certain period of time after they register?

Comment: @clifgray When you create a new user, are you writing it back to your datastore? I could be wrong (I have very limited OpenID experience), but I believe you have to explicitly store a newly registered user in your datastore in order to do what you're looking for. Also, looking at the code again, are you using `User` as the model name for your users?

Comment: oh geez, yes I changed my handler for my homepage and I forgot to add the user to the database.  Silly mistake.  Thanks for the second pair of eyes.  Also yes I am using User as the model name for my users.  I suppose that may not be the best idea with the Users service existing too

Comment: @clifgray Awesome, glad you got it! And yes, you may want to consider changing the name of the model to avoid confusion later :)